# Can I make dhikr in English?

Tags: english, dhikr

I make Dhikr (***Subhanallahi, al adheem, wa bihamdihi***) 112 times morning and evening everyday.
I am a non-native speaker who does not understand Arabic. I do understand what the above dhikr means, "***Glorified is Allah, The Supreme, Praised is he***" but as I say it, it is not clear what I am saying. Thus, I use English translation and Arabic in rounds. The English one has deeper impact on me as I understand what I am saying while the Arabic ones are more or less a mechanical process, with my full heart still.

Can dhikr be  offered in English? Are they accepted? Apparently any form of dhikr should be accepted, nonetheless I would like to be enlightened.

Comment: good question as i also want the answer to it so +1, just from my mind i am saying that since you and me dont understand arabic we like its version in our native language to strenthen the impact of teacing on us i dont think it will be allowed as the same case is not allowed in salaat because we have to offer salaat in arabic Quranic verses, nonetheless i would like someone answer to your question

Answer (score 2):

Assalamu Alaikum,
May Allah accept my prayers and yours. It is strongly encouraged that du'as from the Qur'an and Sunnah, and dhikr be recited in Arabic as that is the language in which they were revealed and it is the language we will rise to speak on the Day of Judgement. For example, as reported by Abu Huraira (RA):

> the Messenger of Allah (SAW) said,
>
> > "there are two statements that are light for the tongue to remember, heavy in the Scales and are dear to the Merciful: 'Subhan-Allahi wa bihamdihi, Subhan-Allahil-Azim (Glory be to Allah and His is the praise and Allah, the Greatest is free from imperfection)
>
> (Al-Bukhari and Muslim).

The hadith above quoted the the arabic text then translates it.
I would encourage you to continue the path you have chosen: reading it in Arabic and translating it for that is how I say Dhikr- the effect is that of soothing and utmost sincerity from knowing the meaning of what is being said.

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum,

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum, unfortunately there aren't hadiths that categorically state that but scholars have strongly recommended the recitation of duas in arabic. Please refer to the author's note in Hisnul Muslim, the link attached: http://islamqa.info/en/20953, http://islamqa.info/en/11588. I'll keep searching.